# Отображение контента сайта с разных ОС

Tags: .htaccess, javascript

Прошу помощи у программистов:

Как осуществить вот такое:

Посетитель сайта зашедший с мобильного устройства (например ОС Android) видит в определенном месте контента одну ссылку, а посетитель зашедший с ОС Windows 7/XP и пр. видит в том же месте другую ссылку. Т.е. отдавать разные ссылки для мобильных и обычных ОС.

Может это можно осуществить с помощью .htaccess и javascript?

Заранее Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте атрибут `HTTP_USER_AGENT` в `RewriteCond`.
Пример:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla.* # - если у пользователя браузер Mozilla Firefox.
RewriteRule ^/$ /homepage.html [L,QSA]
//--- Значения HTTP_USER_AGENT ---
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Opera.* # - если у пользователя браузер Opera.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Chrome.* # - если у пользователя браузер Google Chrome.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Safari.* # - если  у пользователя браузер Safari.
//--- Определение ОС ---
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Win* # - если у пользователя ОС семейства Windows.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Linux* # - если у пользователя ОС семейства Linux.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Unix* # - если у пользователя ОС семейства UNIX.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mac* # - если у пользователя ОС семейства MacOS.
```

Чтобы узнать подробнее о атрибуте `HTTP_USER_AGENT`, используйте [Google](http://www.google.com/)

**UPD:** исправил костыли.
Также можно использовать PHP-функцию: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`

Comment: Приведенные регулярки не годятся. Зачем `^` в каждой? [вариант с SO][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Comment: Прекрасно работает у меня на сервере. Возможно у вас не работает mod_rewrite.